# memory issue in using partially initialized array(in 0/1 knapsack)

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

Given n items with size Ai and value Vi, and a backpack with size m. What's the maximum value can you put into the backpack?

Have you met this question in a real interview? Yes
Example
Given 4 items with size [2, 3, 5, 7] and value [1, 5, 2, 4], and a backpack with size 10. The maximum value is 9.

Note
You cannot divide item into small pieces and the total size of items you choose should smaller or equal to m.

```
    int knapsack(int m, vector<int> A, vector<int> V) {
    int dp[m + 1], tmp[m + 1];


    for (int n = 1; n <= m; n++) { 
     //******the problem would disappear if i change n to start with 0

        dp[n] = (n < A[0]) ? 0 : V[0] ;
        tmp[n] = dp[n];
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < A.size(); i++) {
        for (int n = 1; n <= m; n++) {
            tmp[n] = dp[n];
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
            if (j >= A[i]) {
                dp[j] = max(tmp[j], (V[i] + tmp[j - A[i]]));
            }
        }
    }
    return dp[m];
}
```

**I am failing the specific testcase and all other are fine(even larger m values)
m = 10, A = [2,3,5,7], V = [1,5,2,4]
Output: 563858905 (actually random every time) Expected: 9**

**I know this question is some what trivial but I'm really curious about the memory allocation process in this scenario**

**I'm guessing that it would be dangerous to use any array that is not initialized at the first memory location, can someone confirm with me?**

Comment: What I do not understand is why should you start form 1? It does not matter what are the indices if the size is the same: 0-9, or 1-10, but in your case 0-10 and not using 0 is not normal... "In C++, the first element in an array is always numbered with a zero (not a one), no matter its length" that is the standard, you should respect it!

Comment: I did start at 0 at first but I then realized that it's algorithmically the same if I start with 1, then the memory problem occurred, the question is pretty trivial but I'm just not exactly sure why this happens

Comment: So, you did it correctly and then you decided to not respect the standard and now you are wondering why there are problems...

Answer (score 1):

I tried following code, a simpler version of yours;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int knapsack(int m, int  A[], int V[], int size) {
    int dp[m+1], tmp[m+1];

    for (int n = 1; n <= m; n++) {  //*1*
        dp[n] = (n < A[0]) ? 0 : V[0] ;
        tmp[n] = dp[n];
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) { //*2*
        for (int n = 1; n <= m; n++) { //*3*
            tmp[n] = dp[n];
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++) { //*4*
            if (j >= A[i]) {
                dp[j] = (tmp[j]> (V[i] + tmp[j - A[i]])? //*5*
                                tmp[j] :
                                (V[i] + tmp[j - A[i]])
                                );
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "answer:" << dp[m] << endl;
    return dp[m];
}
int main(){
        int a[]  = {2,3,5,7};
        int b[]  = {1,5,2,4};
        knapsack(10, a, b, 4);
        return 0;
}
```

and got 8 as the answer, rather than a random number.

I'm not sure that my code is the correct version of yours, but I luckily noticed that the expression of `V[i] + tmp[j-A[i]]` at the line marked by "`\\*5`" accesses `tmp[0]` when `j=2` and `i=1`, since `A[1] == 2` and `2 >= A[1]`. Thus it would not be safe without initialization of `tmp[0]` in this logic.

So, I guess you are right; the uninitialized value of `tmp[0]` may change the result value, (and in some cases the flow of the logic as well, at the conditional statement of line `//*5`.)